# Suggested formatting for SQL SELECT return

Tags: python, mysql

I am doing the following pattern in my python code:

```
self.cursor1.execute(
     '''SELECT title, availed_title, episode_number,
               platform_id_series, platform_id_season, 
               platform_id_episode, season_number, url,
               provider_id, country, currency_code, est_hd_offer,                   
               est_sd_offer, vod_hd_offer, vod_sd_offer
     FROM main_googlecatalogtmp WHERE asset_type="episode"'''
)

item = cursor.fetchone()
title, availed_title, platform_id_series,
platform_id_season, platform_id_episode,
season_number, url, provider_id, country,
currency_code, est_hd_offer, est_sd_offer,
vod_hd_offer, vod_sd_offer = item
```

What would be a 'cleaner' way to define all those variables?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `dictCursor`?

Comment: You could use a different kind of cursor/row factory that gives you something like a namedtuple instead of a dict. See [`sqlite3.Row`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects) for an example (of course you'd need to port it to work with MySQL cursors, but it's not that complicated). But I agree with Kevin; I don't see what's wrong with a dict here.

Comment: In general, you rarely want to have 15 separate variables for anything; if you really need that many values, a dict with 15 members or an object with 15 attributes is usually going to be cleaner. Of course "in general" and "usually" doesn't mean "always", but without seeing your code, all I can say is that it's _probably_ the same as most code usually is in general. :)

Comment: @abarnert -- I see, my reasoning for not using a tuple is there are about 10M sql statements using this pattern, and I thought not using the dictCursor would be more efficient. Is that not the case?

Comment: @David542: First, you don't really mean 10 million _statements_, do you? 10 million _rows_ seems like a realistic possibility… but you aren't keeping them all around in memory, are you? A `dictCursor` just converts one row (or maybe one chunk of rows, still only a few KB) at a time into dicts, so it doesn't waste any significant memory.

Comment: @David542: Also, optimizing your code to be more efficient but less readable is only a good tradeoff when the efficiency matters. If you're looking for a way to make this more readable, but you're afraid it might waste too much memory or time, just test it and see.

Comment: @abarnert -- that makes sense. Yes, it would be 10M rows, and then iterating over each of those rows with item = `self.cursor1.fetchone()`.

Comment: By the way, which MySQL wrapper are you using? If it's MySQL's own Python/Connector, they replaced the simple two-cursor choice with a whole slew of cursors a few years ago, so you probably want to explicitly use `mysql.cursor.MySQLCursorDict` or `mysql.cursor.MySQLCursorBufferedNamedTuple` or whatever best fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cleanest" solution might be to use something like SQLAlchemy Core, or even a full ORM, to wrap things up. Then you'd be writing code that just queries for matching objects, and the objects have a `title` attribute, an `episode_number` attribute, etc. But that may be more heavy-duty than you want, or maybe some of your logic doesn't fit the OODB model very well, or maybe that's just too much code to change at this point.

But you can get a step in that direction just by using a `namedtuple`-style cursor or row factory.

Assuming you're using MySQL's own Connector/Python as the interface, you can specify the cursor type explicitly (see [the list of all cursor subclasses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cursor-subclasses.html)), or specify flags and let it choose the cursor type that matches those flags. For example:

```
self.cursor1 = db.cursor(named_tuple=True)
# ...
self.cursor1.execute(
     '''SELECT title, availed_title, episode_number,
               platform_id_series, platform_id_season, 
               platform_id_episode, season_number, url,
               provider_id, country, currency_code, est_hd_offer,                   
               est_sd_offer, vod_hd_offer, vod_sd_offer
     FROM main_googlecatalogtmp WHERE asset_type="episode"'''
)
item = cursor.fetchone()
print('My title is {}'.format(item.title))
```

Depending on your use case, a `dict` might fit better than a `namedtuple`. For example:

```
self.cursor1 = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
# ...
self.cursor1.execute(
     '''SELECT title, availed_title, episode_number,
               platform_id_series, platform_id_season, 
               platform_id_episode, season_number, url,
               provider_id, country, currency_code, est_hd_offer,                   
               est_sd_offer, vod_hd_offer, vod_sd_offer
     FROM main_googlecatalogtmp WHERE asset_type="episode"'''
)
item = cursor.fetchone()
print('My title is {title} and my url is {url}'.format(**item))
```

For performance tradeoffs, the same fully-buffered/rowset-buffered/row-buffered options that control how many rows are read and type-converted at a time also control how many rows are wrapped up in a dict or namedtuple. It may be a little faster to buffer as much as possible, but of course it costs memory; when you really need to fine-tune things, the best answer may be to break a result into multiple result sets of exactly the right size and fully buffer each of them, but normally that isn't worth doing.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the clarity this helps a lot in giving me some options to test with. I'll let you know what I find as far as performance.